# Drag and drop file on Flutter web is not working properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-web-browser

**Works when url project run on browser manually**

As shown below

[image: Drag and drop working properly]

**Not works when project run from**

vscode (start debugging or Run without debugging)

or

`> flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit`

or

`> flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`

As shown below

[image: drag and drop not working]

I did some exploration (not resolve the problem)

- Maybe vscode run using mode renderer html (must be canvaskit)
- Package flutter_dropzone not working well with flutter web (https://github.com/deakjahn/flutter_dropzone/issues/24), so need to use subPlugin which is `flutter_dropzone_web`

i'm just wondering why this happened
Please give explanation if any of you guys have the same problem before

fyi,

- run on Flutter web
- using Package `flutter_dropzone: ^3.0.5`
- default example code from example using Package `flutter_dropzone'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain more what "running manually" means? vs flutter run etc

Comment: Running manually by copy paste the url e.g: `http://localhost:56743/#/ `   ,


and run `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit` , via terminal

Answer (score 0):

try it after build. i think it is because of plugin.dll file generated

Comment: This should be a comment even though you don't have enough reputation